# Rendering FreeType Fonts in Opengl

Tags: opengl, freetype

I've linked to FreeType and used the mini library from [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/NeHe) to try and draw a sample string to the screen and I get this where glitchy outlines of the letters are drawn in the bottom left.

[image: Text rendered with whiteish borders around it]

The code below is how I am drawing, just like in the example.

```
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glColor3ub(0xff,0xff,0xff);
freetype::print(font, 10, 10, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-=[]()!?");
glPopMatrix();
```

There's no exceptions being thrown and it compiles fine so I'm finding it difficult to troubleshoot. Can anyone tell by the screenshot what the issue is likely to be?

Comment: I believe what was causing the trouble was the line `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);` which I used to draw a frame of a cube.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like smoothing/antialiasing turned on, and spoil your image. Try turn off all smoothing when draw text.

Comment: I tried `glDisable(GL_BLEND);` before the print but it didn't change anything. Antialiasing is enabled through GLFW with `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);` at the start, commenting out the line improved the result somewhat but is still [bad](http://i.snag.gy/aUz6p.jpg). Is there anything in particular I should enable or disable before the draw?

Comment: May be this will help?  http://axfive.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/freetype-texture-fonts-in-opengl/

Comment: Not really, its using deprecated libraries getting too many compiler errors.

Comment: The last thing, I remember that I've got freetype+opengl functions from opensource framework from here: http://www.openframeworks.cc/

Comment: I don't know NeHe but with ftgl ( an opengl layer above freetype2 ) there is a lot of modes to draw the text, check if you are using outline fonts, polygon fonts or textured fonts. Keep in mind that you need to setup your opengl context according to the type you are tracing.